# Edges, Vertices and faces didnt show in my mesh vert

Tags: modeling

I have a problem which i added the single vert mesh but there was no edges, vertices and faces show up that can be selected. When I changed to edit mode there was not vertices shows up. .Is there any solution of this ?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's looks like that you add vertex *inside* existing mesh. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: when i added a new mesh vert and changed to edit mode. There are no edges, vertices and faces show up in the shape for me to edit the shape. 

Sorry english arent my 1st language I'll try to elaborate more if you ask more :)

Comment: How do i know i add the vertex inside existing mesh ?

Comment: Select the object, go in Edit mode / Vertex selection, select all, you should see the additional vertex

Comment: still nothing shows up.

Comment: The new vert should be added at the cursor position. If your other object is hiding it, select it in Object mode and hit 'H' to hide it. To unhide it use ALT-H.

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode*, Press <kbd>A</kbd> twice to make sure nothing is selected. Now <kbd>2</kbd> for edge selection mode. <kbd>A</kbd> again to select all edges. <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them. <kbd>1</kbd> for vertex selection mode. <kbd>A</kbd> to select all stray vertices:

[image]

(on the GIF I'm first selecting a few vertices and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to create a few stray vertices)

As pointed by batFINGER, you can also do `Select > Select All By Trait > Loose Geometry` if you don't want the rest deselected.

Comment: Is this same as _`Select > Select All By Trait > Loose Geometry`_ in vert mode?